# Multidocker environment, amazon beanstalk, mounting volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, mount, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, volumes

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I have a docker container which contains a CMS, that CMS has a folder named 'assets'. I need the asset folder to be available to other containers, and also for the data to be safe from deletion when containers/images are removed.

**How I've attempted to solve it:** I have read all about mounting volumes in multi container environments and looked at a bunch of examples and came up with the following dockerrun.aws.json file

```
{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
 "volumes": [
{
  "name": "assets",
  "host": {
    "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/cms"
  }
}
],
"containerDefinitions": [
{
  //...
  "mountPoints": [
    {
      "sourceVolume": "assets",
      "containerPath": "/var/www/assets",
      "readOnly": false
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I can upload this via Beanstalk and everything builds and all boxes are green, however if I login to the EC2 instance and ls /var/app/current the directory is empty. I was expecting to see /var/app/current/cms/assets sitting there...

I think I'm missing a core concept or flag in my build file, any direction or better way of achieving what I'm trying to do would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at this link and try it out.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html
I believe this is similar to what you are asking for.
J